# Why my Task is not getting to cancel and recreate multiple times?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Requirement : Multiple BLE Hardwares(device) will broadcast advertisement data every second ,we need to receive the data and indicate(GREEN) the particular device in mobile application.
If the any of the Hardware stops broadcasting, I need to change colour RED after 30 sec. If incase the hardware sends packet before 30 sec time frame, we need to be reset task and should retain the GREEN status only.

Current Approach : We have created a task which will wait for 30 sec and change device colour to red. As and when we receive data new data from same hardware, we are cancelling running task and creating the new one.

Problem statement : The current approach is works as expected less than 1 min. After that task cancel will not happen as expected.

Please suggest.

```
var deviceDetectedDict = new Dictionary<string,CancellationTokenSource>();

if (deviceDetectedDict.ContainsKey(seatName))
{
    CancellationTokenSource cTokenSource = deviceDetectedDict[seatName];
    if (cTokenSource != null)
    {
        cTokenSource.Cancel();
        deviceDetectedDict.Remove(seatName);
        cTokenSource.Dispose();
        CreateTask(lockedseatIDUIIV, seatName);
    }
}
else 
{
    CreateTask(lockedseatIDUIIV, seatName); 
}

private void CreateTask(UIImageView _seatIDUIIV, string _seatID)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    deviceDetectedDict.Add(_seatID, cts);
    Task myTask = new Task(() => 
        CreateTaskWithTimer(_seatIDUIIV, cts.Token, _seatID));
    myTask.Start();
}

private async void CreateTaskWithTimer(UIImageView view, CancellationToken ct, string seat)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread ID created = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            ChangeImageToLocked(ImageGREEN);
        });

        await Task.Delay(30000, ct);

        BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            ChangeImageToUnLocked(ImageRED);
        });    
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oc)
    {
       Console.WriteLine( seat + " Task cancelled :"+ ""+ oc.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task have a really bad design.

Here is how it could look like

```
private async Task CreateTaskWithTimerAsync( UIImageView seatImageView, CancellationToken ct,string seat )
{
    ChangeImageToLocked(ImageGREEN);
    await Task.Delay( 30000, ct );
    ChangeImageToUnLocked(ImageRED);
}

private void CreateTask(UIImageView _seatIDUIIV, string _seatID)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    deviceDetectedDict.Add(_seatID, cts);
    var _ = CreateTaskWithTimerAsync(_seatIDUIIV, cts.Token, _seatID));
}
```